# Idiomatic Event engine in Scala

Tags: events, scala

I have a problem where some objects change their properties based on some internal logic. For the sake of simplicity, let's imagine an object `RandomSource` that has a public `Int` field named `Value`. The object has its own thread and, sometimes, it updates the `Value` field.

Now, other objects in the system are interested in being notified that the `Value` was updated. In C#, I could define a companion delegate that objects subscribe, and which it is raised when the property is updated.

My question is thus the following: how do I do this in Scala? Which is the most "idiomatic" solution?

Comment: I think probable solution is [FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) (something like ScalaFX)

Comment: I am using http://eventbus.org with Scala

Comment: There's an interesting related paper at http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf

Comment: The article "counting word 2" http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/search/label/gui is a good illustration of FRP, using reactive framework (https://github.com/nafg/reactive), like a Signal, for instance: http://reactive-web.tk/core/Signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observers are still pretty standard, also known as Publisher/Listener. You can roll your own, or you could use some actor-based solution if you want async notifications.

On the functional side, this stuff is more often done through functional reactive frameworks. There's Naftoli's  [Reactive](https://github.com/nafg/reactive), but [Akka](http://akka.io) also provides a `Dataflow`, which amounts to very much the basic concepts.

Beyond these, this is a field of research on the evolution of Scala, so you can be sure you'll see more of them.

Comment: +1 see for instance http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/10/counting-words-part-2.html